# Mongoose Find() doesnt work with variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello im trying to query my mongoDB collection to find all data from specific date.
For some reason when I use Find() with the object specified as param in the call  it works
but when I try to declare a variable it doesnt .... can some explain me why?

this doesnt work

```
    //Convert Date to short Date string
    let day = foundRapport.date.getUTCDate();
    let fullMonth = foundRapport.date.getMonth() + 1;
    let year = foundRapport.date.getFullYear();
    let date = `${day}/${fullMonth}/${year}`;

    //query for Date_Travail
    let query = {};
    let criteria = "Date_Travail";
    query[criteria] = date;
    console.log(query); // this returns { Date_Travail: '24/7/2020' }

    //Find data with query as param
    Heures.find(query, (err, foundHours) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.render("rapportDetail", {
          rapport: foundRapport,
          shortDate: date,
          hours: foundHours,
        });
      }
    });
```

But this here does....

```
    //Convert Date to short Date string
    let day = foundRapport.date.getUTCDate();
    let fullMonth = foundRapport.date.getMonth() + 1;
    let year = foundRapport.date.getFullYear();

    let date = `${day}/${fullMonth}/${year}`;

    // let query = {};
    // let criteria = "Date_Travail";
    // query[criteria] = date;
    // console.log(query);

    //Find data with object as param
    Heures.find({Date_Travail: "24/07/2020"}, (err, foundHours) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.render("rapportDetail", {
          rapport: foundRapport,
          shortDate: date,
          hours: foundHours,
        });
      }
    });
```

can anyone point me on the direction of why?
Thanks

Comment: The date is different though, the one with variable is `24/7/2020`, and your manual one is `24/07/2020` (`7` and `07`)

Comment: My man..! thanks... I feel like an idiot! I been on this like for hours, finally decided to ask Stack cause I didnt see a reason why its shouldn't work...and to be this...
anyways thanks again